# Testing using a Mockito in Spring boot app of a method that takes the Model as a parameter

Tags: java, mockito, modelandview

I need to write a test testing the getData(Model model) @Service method via Mockito.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class RestCtrl {

   @Autowired
   private TestService testService;

   @GetMapping
   public ModelAndView getData(Model model) {
       return testService.getData(model)
   }
}

@Service
public class TestService {

   @Autowired
   private TestServiceRepository testServiceRepository;
 
   public ModelAndView getData(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("data", testServiceRepository.findAll());
      return new ModelAndView("index");
   }

}


public interface TestServiceRepository extends JpaRepository<TestDTO, Long> {
}
```

Is it possible write test on a @Service method that returns ModelAndView ?

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TestServiceClass {
   @InjectMocks
   private TestService testService;

   @Mock
   private TestServiceRepository testServiceRepository;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

You can use Mockito to mock an instance of `ModelAndView` via simple call to `Mockito.mock(ModelAndView.class);`

Comment: this is true but does not really answers the question. He should do sth. like that in his test method:

var result = Mockito.mock(ModelAndView.class);
 when(testServiceRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(List.of(result));